# Is there a way to call a post from another view in Django?

Tags: python, django, url, post

I want to process the `POST` in `Processing` view when I type `next/` URL directly on the browser bar, any clue? I'm including the repository just in case:
https://github.com/ivanperezdesigner/Hypercar
thank's for your help

***views.py file***

```py
class Processing(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {'service_line': service_line}
        return render(request, 'tickets/processing.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(service_line['change_oil']) > 0:
            service_line['change_oil'].pop(0)
        elif len(service_line['inflate_tires']) > 0:
            service_line['inflate_tires'].pop(0)
        elif len(service_line['diagnostic']) > 0:
            service_line['diagnostic'].pop(0)
        return redirect('/next')

class Next(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        x = 0
        if len(service_line['change_oil']) > 0:
            x = service_line['change_oil'][0]
        elif len(service_line['inflate_tires']) > 0:
            x = service_line['inflate_tires'][0]
        elif len(service_line['diagnostic']) > 0:
            x = service_line['diagnostic'][0]
        context = {'next': x}
        return render(request, 'tickets/next.html', context)
```

---

***urls.py file***

```py
from django.urls import path
from tickets.views import WelcomeView, MenuView, Service, Processing, Next
from django.views.generic import RedirectView


urlpatterns = [
    path('welcome/', WelcomeView.as_view()),
    path('menu/', MenuView.as_view()),
    path('get_ticket/<str:service>', Service.as_view()),
    path('processing/', Processing.as_view()),
    path('next/', Next.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Put it's content in a function and call that function.